# Group Chat Feature

Tags: c#, xamarin, chat, xamarin.forms, groupchat

I want to add a chat to my xamarin.forms app.
I've read alot of documentations about creating chats in c# but still I couldn't get an answer some of my questions:

- What is the best(performance) way to create a chatroom(like a groupchat) i've read using a thread per room could be a solution but this seems senseless to me ...
- Is there any Git-Projekt which implements a groupchat function where I can get some insights ?
- What do I have to keep in mind in terms of my infrastructure - how can I connect my chat to SQL ?

I know these are alot of questions but I really dont  know where to start.
I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: You should take a look at SignalR, there are a lot of guides on how to create a chat application with it.

Comment: @AndreasFredriksson wow that looks nice - never heard of it before

Comment: Chat? Text or voice?

Comment: @DannyChen TextChat should do it at first ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using [PubNub](https://github.com/pubnub/c-sharp) for a while, and its awesome.

You can consult examples in [Android](https://github.com/pubnub/c-sharp/tree/master/mono-for-android) and [iOS](https://github.com/pubnub/c-sharp/tree/master/monotouch).

It has full PCL support so you don't have to do specific Android/iOS code to exchange messages.
I've also read a lot of the [tests](https://github.com/pubnub/c-sharp/tree/master/PCL/PubNub-Messaging.Tests) they have in the PCL and get good information from that.

---

You have [Real Time Framework](https://framework.realtime.co/blog/launching-xamarin-sdk.html), to exchange real time messages.

---

They also have a very good [support](https://www.pubnub.com/support/).

For the SQL, you have [SQLite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net).

Comment: Please @Nudity mark my answer as correct if it helped you. Thank you

Comment: I wont forget about it :D just tryin to implement that chat you reccomended to my app ^^

Comment: Ok. they have very very good support, plus they have good examples to.